# Tracking revisions with external txt file

Tags: xifthen

I made the following code to add a revision number to my latex header. I rely on a .txt file, which is assumed to

1. exist in the same directory.
2. always have a number. Anything else will probably make it break

The packages I use are:

---

```
\usepackage{xifthen} 
\usepackage{calculator}
```

---

The code to get the number from the txt file and increment it by one is:

---

```
\newread\file   %starts a new file reader
\openin\file=tracking.txt   %define 'file' as the 'tracking.txt' file from the tex directory
\def\lastNum{}   %declares a variable
\read\file to \lastNum  %read the content of the txt file into the variable
\ADD{1}{\lastNum}{\version} %increment it by 1 and saves in a new variable
\newwrite\file          %starts a file writer
\immediate\openout\file=tracking.txt   % open the file
\immediate\write\file{\version}      %write the new incremented value
\closeout\file        %closes the file
```

---

I then use the \version in my header.

I would like to make this a little more robust and reusable. So I have been trying to find ways to handle cases like:

1. if the tracking.txt file does not exist, then create it.
2. if the tracking.txt exists, but empty or has some illegal text, then start at 0 (write zero to it). Illegal text would be anything other than an a number

using the xifthen package, i added this line of code...

---

```
\ifthenelse{isempty{read\file}}{\lastNum{0}}{read\file to \lastNum}
```

---

This is the full, non working, version:

---

```
\newread\file   %starts a new file reader
\openin\file=tracking.txt   %define 'file' as the 'tracking.txt' file from the tex directory
\def\lastNum{}   %declares a variable
\read\file to \lastNum  %read the content of the txt file into the variable
\ifthenelse{isempty{read\file}}{\lastNum{0}}{read\file to \lastNum} %check
\ADD{1}{\lastNum}{\version} %increment it by 1 and saves in a new variable
\newwrite\file          %starts a file writer
\immediate\openout\file=tracking.txt   % open the file
\immediate\write\file{\version}      %write the new incremented value
\closeout\file        %closes the file
```

---

I keep getting errors in the ADD method.. there is something wrong in the read file I think. Any tips would be highly appreciated! I am new to latex programming-- please excuse my primitive questions and crude code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the aux file, and latex's label-ref system?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \newcounter{version}        % start version counter, associated label is lblversion
    \setcounterref{version}{lblversion} % init counter to label value (thanks to refcount)
    \stepcounter{version}       % step to counter for current version, add corresponding label
    \immediate\write\@auxout{   % while we're at it, let's write immediately current version number
        \string
        \newlabel{lblversion}{{\theversion}{}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\theversion

\chapter{chap1}
\end{document}
```

Each compilation will add one to the counter `version`, memorised by the label `lblversion`. However I haven't (yet) found how to get rid of the 'Label(s) may have changed' warning...
Also, this is enclosed in a `AtBeginDocument` which might be problematic if you want the version number in the title, but as the aux file is read just before the `\begin{document}`, it is necessary (as long as you use the aux file).

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. One last question, how do I control the increment. Because of the Latex, BibTex, Latex, Latex, pdflatexs command, it jumps 4 steps at a time.  Any ideas?

Comment: The version comes in the header and front page just fine which is what I need the most. The file name can remain as is.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer cannot work for headers as it reads the aux file at begin{document}. However, like you did with a dedicated file, and the `InputIfFileExists` command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{version}                        % start version counter, no label here
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.version}{}{}    % read from file, if it exists (might want to consider a ./\jobname.version here to limit to the working folder)
\stepcounter{version}

\makeatletter
{%
  \if@filesw                                                % respect \nofiles
    \begingroup
      \chardef\reserved@c=15                                % same write register as environment `filecontents` uses
      \immediate\openout\reserved@c=\jobname.version\relax  % open/create file to read/write to
      \immediate\write\reserved@c{%                         % instead of writing only version number, we write the assignment
        \string\setcounter{version}{\theversion}%
      }%
      \immediate\closeout\reserved@c
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\theversion

\end{document}
```

This snippet is not really my own (though adapted here to your needs), but I have been using for my external file needs since I found it on tex.sx and I have trouble finding the question again...

Comment: Thanks! I went with the second answer since it uses the aux :)